# dropbox connector, no callback uri, Could not find connector with name 'connector.http.mule.default'

Tags: callback, mule, dropbox, connector

i'm new to Mule and i'm trying to use the dropbox connector with my web application. I'm trying to make a flow to authorize the current user to upload a file, however the flow doesn't even run. All i did was set up an http connector, then placed the dropbox connector and set it up. I used the graphic interface but here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<dropbox:config name="Dropbox" appKey="xxxxxxxxxxx" appSecret="xxxxxxxxxxx" doc:name="Dropbox">
    <dropbox:oauth-callback-config domain="http://localhost" localPort="8081"  path="callback" remotePort="8081"/>
</dropbox:config>
<dropbox:config name="Dropbox1" appKey="xxxxxxxxxxx" appSecret="xxxxxxxxxxx" doc:name="Dropbox">
    <dropbox:oauth-callback-config domain="http://localhost" localPort="8081" remotePort="8081" path="callback"/>
</dropbox:config>
<flow name="dropbxFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/callback/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <dropbox:authorize config-ref="Dropbox" doc:name="Dropbox"/>
</flow>
```

i keep getting this error when i run : 
INFO  2015-05-05 16:09:53,688 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting model: _muleSystemModel
INFO  2015-05-05 16:09:53,688 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager: Starting flow: dropbxFlow
INFO  2015-05-05 16:09:53,688 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.processor.SedaStageLifecycleManager: Starting service: dropbxFlow.stage1
ERROR 2015-05-05 16:09:53,694 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.modules.dropbox.process.DefaultHttpCallback: Could not find connector with name 'connector.http.mule.default'
INFO  2015-05-05 16:09:53,694 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.processor.SedaStageLifecycleManager: Stopping service: dropbxFlow.stage1
ERROR 2015-05-05 16:09:53,890 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
org.mule.api.DefaultMuleException: Could not find connector with name 'connector.http.mule.default'

This only happens when i use the Authorize attribute on the dropbox connector, as it needs a callback uri(which i think it the problem here), the callback http endpoint isn't being set up. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: nevermind, i fixed it by changing the connector, i was using the wrong connector named "Mule Dropbox Cloud Connector Mule Studio Extension"

Comment: i am facing the same issue with salesforce. Could you elaborate a little how u did fix this issue - thank you

Comment: @Jaguar, i simply changed the connector to an updated one, not sure about salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

These are normal version issues with some of the libraries. I had the same issue while using dropbox connector 3.3.0 so after a lot of R&D I figured out where was actually the problem. I went to pom.xml, there I changed version to 3.3.3 and all was fine and running and no more issue at all.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
 <artifactId>mule-module-dropbox</artifactId>
 <version>3.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And regarding that "no callback uri", you should have same redirect uri in dropbox developer account and in dropbox global element Oauth configuration.
Let's say you have provided "http://localhost:8081/callback" as Redirect URI in Dropbox account so your Oauth configuration should be like as following

```
         Domain         :    localhost

         Local Port     :    8081

         Remote Port    :    8081

         Path           :    callback
```